# Gulp сборка с gulp-hash?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, frontend

Использую для сборки **gulp** и плагины **gulp-hash**, **gulp-useref**.

**gulpfile.js** выглядит так:

```
    'use strict';

var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    useref       = require('gulp-useref'),
    hash         = require('gulp-hash');

// Пути
var path = {
  app : {          // Исходники
    html   : 'app/*.html',
    js     : 'app/js/**/*.js'
  },
  dist : {         // Релиз
    html   : 'dist/',
    js     : 'dist/js/'
  },
  watch : {        // Наблюдение
    html   : 'app/**/*.html',
    js     : 'app/js/**/*.js',
  }
};

// Работа с HTML
gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src(path.app.html)   
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html));
});

// Работа с JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
  gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(hash())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
});

// Наблюдение
gulp.task('watch', function () {    
  gulp.watch(path.watch.html, ['html']);
  gulp.watch(path.watch.js, ['js']); 
});

// Задачи по-умолчанию
gulp.task('default', [
  'html',
  'js'  
]);
```

В **index.html**:

```
  <!-- build:js js/main.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>   
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

userefом собираю main.js.

Структура:

```
-app
  |__ js
  |     |__ main.js
  |__ index.html

-dist
  |__ js
  |     |__ main.js
  |     |__ main-b5d60504.js
  |__ index.html

-gulpfile.js
-package.json
```

**Вопрос:**

Как можно поправить **gulpfile.js**, чтобы на выходе сборки в **dist/index.html** был подключен хэшированный файл **main-b5d60504.js**, а не main.js как сейчас? И чтобы в **dist/js** собирался только хэшированный файл скрипта?

Comment: непонятно для чего именно здесь `useref` используется

Comment: В данном примере можно и без него!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простых случаев можно воспользоваться поиском/заменой, с помощью [gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace).

Для этого вам понадобится знать новое имя переименованного плагином gulp-hash файла. Это можно сделать сохранив список переименованных файлов с помощью `hash.manifest('assets.json')`, а затем прочитав его в задаче 'html', чтобы использовать для поиска/замены.

Также обратите внимание, что используется `return` в задачах (в вашем примере их нет), в противном случае зависимые задачи будут запускаться не дожидаясь завершения задач от которых они зависят.

В данном случае важно, что сначала будет отработана задача 'js', чтобы получить новое имя файла, а затем задача 'html', чтобы сделать замену в тексте.

Пример `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  replace = require('gulp-replace'),
  hash = require('gulp-hash');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/*')
    .pipe(hash())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(hash.manifest('assets.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['js'], function() {
  var assets = require('./tmp/assets.json');
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(replace('main.js', assets['main.js']))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['html'], function() {

});
```

Comment: что-то не так (
Error: Cannot find module '../tmp/assets.json'

путь и так как у вас и так ../tmp/assets.json и так tmp/assets.json прописываю и никак ))

Comment: проверьте куда assets.json в вашем случае сохраняется

Comment: app, dist, tmp на одном уровне

Comment: тогда наверное одна точка нужна в пути, вместо двух (./tmp/assets.json)

Comment: ага, поняла, беда в том, что tmp создается после [html] ... странно, ведь js отрабатывает , а потом уже html идет

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko поэтому задача `js` стоит в зависимостях у `html` в примере (чтобы задача `html` выполнялась только после `js`). Также не забывайте `return`.

Comment: gulp.task('html', ['js'], function() { 
я же поставила все так же, но ... а про return не понятно
в описании плагинов вроде нет

Comment: Без `return` не будет ожидания завершения задачи.

Comment: return помог, спасибо!!!